# Sequential prize searching

Tags: combinatorial-optimization

There are $N$ rooms. In each room $i$, with probability $p_i$ one can find a prize. The cost of searching room $i$ for the prize is $c_i$. A user can search at most $n$ out of $N$ rooms. If a prize is found, he gets a unit reward and stops searching. The problem is to find the sequence of rooms to be searched so as to maximize his expected utility defined as the reward minus the cost.

Mathematically, suppose the user searches rooms $1$ to $n$ sequentially, his overall utility can be written as:
$$U=1-(1-p_1)(1-p_2)\cdots(1-p_n)-[p_1c_1+(1-p_1)p_2(c_1+c_2)+\cdots+(1-p_1)\cdots(1-p_{n-2})p_{n-1}(c_1+\cdots+c_{n-1})+(1-p_1)\cdots(1-p_{n-2})(1-p_{n-1})(c_1+\cdots+c_n)].$$

With some algebraic operations and by defining $q_i=1-p_i$, the problem of maximizing $U$ can be mapped to the problem of minimizing the following function $V$:
$$V=q_1\cdots q_n+(c_1+q_1c_2+q_1q_2c_3+\cdots+q_1\cdots q_{n-1}c_n).$$

My question is how to solve the combinatorial optimization problem of minimizing $V$? Is there any known problem that can help?

Comment: This looks like a typical problem in dynamic programming. What is known about the prizes $c_i$? $c_i \geq 0$? Is it allowed to stop searching before $n$ rooms are searched if the price is too high? What about the policy first search in the room with $p_i/c_i$ largest, then second largest, ... Have you tried it?

Comment: @DieterKadelka Thank you. DP is definately a choice. However, I am more interested in polynomial algorithms, e.g., constant-factor approximation algo.

Answer (score 1):

A solution to the problem is an ordered list of $n$ rooms. If $n=N$, Dieter Kadelka's suggestion (searching the rooms in order of decreasing $p_i/c_i$) can be followed  and gives an optimal solution computable in linear time. This can be shown by looking at how $V$ changes if two rooms that would be searched consecutively are exchanged.

If $n<N$, an optimal solution can still be found in polynomial time using dynamic programming. By the reasoning above, we can assume that the rooms are ordered by decreasing $p_i/c_i$ and that a subset of them are searched in that order. It remains to find the subset.

Let $U_{max}(r,l)$ be the maximum expected reward obtainable by searching at most $r$ rooms among the (last) $l$ rooms numbered from $N-l+1$ to $N$. For $r>0$, $l>0$, we have $$U_{max}(r,l) = max(p_{N-l+1}-c_{N-l+1}+q_{N-l+1}\cdot U_{max}(r-1,l-1), U_{max}(r,l-1))$$. This enables us to compute $U_{max}$ for $l$ and all possible $r$'s easily if $U_{max}$ is known for $l-1$. 
We can thus use dynamic programming to compute $U_{max}(r,l)$ for all $0\leq r\leq n$ and $0\leq l\leq N$ in time $O(n\cdot N)$.

An optimal subset of rooms can then be computed in $O(N)$ time from the function $U_{max}$. By a careful computation of the subset of rooms in the same time as $U_{max}$, the algorithm could even be made to run in space $O(N)$.

Comment: Thank you jmd. I am afraid I did not quite get your DP approach, could you pls develop it a little bit for me? We are interested in the non-trivial case $n<N$ and given the set of rooms to be searched, searching them in the decreasing order of $p_i/c_i$ is optimal.

Comment: I edited my answer to make it more explicit. I write a comment since I am not sure if you are notified of edits.

Comment: Thank you. I agree with the DP formulation. HOwever, it seems that it is not easy to calculate $U(0,0)$, which equals $U(n,N)$ (which is the maximal utility we need to compute) if I understand correctly.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. The border cases are easy: $U_{max}(0,\cdot) = U_{max}(\cdot,0) = 0$, since you cannot search any room in either case.

Comment: thank you and sorry for the late reply. The DP algo is now clear to me. My last question is about how to make the space complexity $O(N)$, i.e., how to maintain the optimal set of rooms to access when computing $U_{max}$?